# How can I make 0>All() return false when the subquery returns nothing?

Tags: sql

How can I make `0>All()` return `false` when the subquery returns nothing?
Logically, for my case, All() can't be <0 if there is nothing in all().

example:

```
select x from table 
where  0 > ALL(complex subquery)
```

How do I modify this so that it returns false for empty list. The subquery is long and complex, and I don't want to repeat it twice, once for exists() and once for 0>ALL()

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
select x 
from table
where  x > (SELECT MAX(foo) 
                 FROM complex_subquery 
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(foo))
```

If the subquery returns no rows then `select MAX(foo)` will return `NULL` and `x > NULL` evaluates to `unknown` so won't be returned by the `WHERE`.

If there are any `NULL` values of `foo` then the `HAVING` clause is there to ensure the query returns no rows so that the correct semantics for `ALL` are maintained (as pointed out by [@hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd))

Comment: +1 The question specifically asks for a "false" return, but I think "unknown" will do :)

Comment: In that light, nicely worded with the "does not evaluate to `true`", by the way :)

Comment: Thinking some more... Your answer assumes (possibly correctly) that the complex subquery does not return null values. `where 1 > max({ 0, null })` (pseudo-SQL) evaluates to true, but `where 1 > all({ 0, null })` does not.

Answer (score 2):

(I'd recommend Martin Smith's answer over this one.)

One option is a CTE:

```
; with  CteAlias as
        (
        ... complex subquery ...
        )
select  col1 
from    table 
where   exists (select * from CteAlias)
        and x > ALL (select col1 from CteAlias)
```

This only works if the subquery is not correlated with the table.

Comment: I think you missed the "I don't want to repeat it twice" in the question, but when repeating it twice isn't an issue, I'd personally prefer `WHERE EXISTS(complex subquery) AND x > ALL(complex subquery)`

Comment: @hvd: Good points :)  I kind of side tracked towards this answer from a CTE

Comment: I deleted my answer as didn't have the right semantics if the subquery could return `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the values returned from the `complex query` in a table variable/temp table and then use that in your main query, unless this complex subquery is dependant on the main query?

Furthermore, you might want to look at using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the complex query, and reuse the code in such a fashion.

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a
>   CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in
>   the same query.